# Использование в проекте кусков кода из нескольких других

Tags: лицензирование

Занимаюсь своим проектом на MonoGame, который впоследствии собираюсь сделать open-source. Порой использую куски кода из других open-source проектов, иногда с переработкой под свои нужды, иногда без.

https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore (GNU General Public License v2.0)
https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended (MIT License)
https://github.com/Wargus/stratagus (GNU General Public License v2.0)
https://github.com/clintbellanger/flare-engine (GNU General Public License v3.0)

И я вот не знаю, если когда-нибудь моему проекту суждено будет оказаться где-то дальше моего компа, то могут ли возникнуть проблемы с лицензированием кусков когда, взятых из других проектов?

Во всех лицензиях есть требование - указание лицензии и соответствие лицензии проекта-приемника проекту-родителю.

Как быть, и что делать?

(Можно, конечно, содрать код и переработать его достаточно сильно, чтобы он не был похожим на оригинальный, но раз это open-source, то почему бы не сделать это без каких-то ухищрений?)

Comment: GPLv2 и GPLv3 несовместимы, так что ваш проект не имеет права на существование

Comment: Т.е. код лежит в открытом доступе, но использовать его я права не имею?)

Comment: Имеете, но только по условиям лицензии. GPLv2 требует распространять всё производное по лицензии GPLv2. GPLv3 - по GPLv3. Если ваш проект будет по лицензии GPLv2, вы нарушите лицензию GPLv3. Если ваш проект будет по GPLv3, вы нарушите GPLv2.

Comment: Понял, видимо, придется выбирать наиболее богатый для копипастинга проект и брать лицензию от него, а для всего остального писать аналогичный по функциям, но отличный по внешнему виду код. Можете написать ответ, приму.

Comment: Не хочу спешить с ответом, я не юрист и вдруг я не прав) Возможно, кто-нибудь на этом сайте ещё возразит

Comment: А вообще GNU предоставляет костыль в виде "GPLv2 or later". Вы можете попробовать попросить авторов GPLv2 проектов перелицензировать их на "GPLv2 or later", и если они согласятся, то проект сможет существовать по GPLv3. (Лицензия MIT, кстати, подобных требований не имеет)

Comment: Я не думаю, что довольно-таки масштабные проекты вроде TrinityCore будут менять лицензию по просьбе какого-то "dude" из города N где-то в России.